# How to propel the integration of time a little bit further? Numerical solution can not evolve to the max time

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I try to solve a nonlinear partial differential equation. I obtain a numerical solution which can not continue to the max time I set, I always receive message

> NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t ==...,

and

> NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of ...at t =.... in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance.

This is my naive code.

```
ini = NDSolve[{D[h[x, t], t] + D[h[x, t]^-1*D[h[x, t], x], x] + 
 D[h[x, t]^3*D[h[x, t], {x, 3}], x] == 0, 
h[-((3 Sqrt[2] π)/2), t] == h[(Sqrt[2] π)/2, t], 
h[x, 0] == 1 + 1/10*Sin[x/Sqrt[2]]}, 
h, {x, -((3 Sqrt[2] π)/2), (Sqrt[2] π)/2}, {t, 0, 6}, 
Method ->{"MethodOfLines",(*"DiscretizedMonitorVariables"->True,*)
Method -> {"FixedStep",(*"StepSize"->0.0001,*)
  Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, 
    "StepSizeControlParameters" -> {3/10, 
      0},(*"StepSizeSafetyFactors"->{8/10,9/10},*)
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal -> 8, 
      "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}}, 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "MinPoints" -> 180, 
  "MaxPoints" -> 
   180}}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 32, StepMonitor :> Print[t]]
```

I have tried `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` and `"Adams"`, and tried to adjust `AccuracyGoal`, but it does not work.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe there is **not** a singularity at or near the stopping point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the plot of `h[-(Sqrt[2]*π)/2, t]` looks something like this,

[image: h(x0, t)]

and that the differential equation has a singularity at `h == 0`, one might expect that `NDSolve` ought not to continue the solution to the max time the OP sets, which is `t == 6`.  `NDSolve` might do it, but that would be because of numerical error when `h` is close to zero (insufficient accuracy).

The solution is symmetric with respect to `x == -(Sqrt[2]*π)/2`, the derivative $\partial h/\partial x$ along this line is zero.  For the time integration along this line, therefore, the differential equation is equivalent to
$${\partial h \over \partial t} + {1 \over h}\; {\partial^2 h \over \partial x^2} + h^3\; {\partial^4 h \over \partial x^4} = 0\,.$$
When $h \approx 0$, assuming ${\partial^4 h / \partial x^4}$ does not grow too fast, we can reduce this to
$${\partial h \over \partial t} \approx - {1 \over h}\; {\partial^2 h \over \partial x^2}\,.$$
Thus the value of the time derivative will be very large and the step `NDSolve` will be very small (the equation becomes stiff).  If in taking a discrete step, `NDSolve` pushes the value of `h` across zero, the time derivative changes sign.  The solution can then be expected to bounce back and forth across zero.  With `AccuracyGoal -> 10`, one might expect the solution to oscillate between $\pm 10^{-10}$ or so (see below).  The step size at this point turns out to be around $10^{-20}$, which means it would take forever to carry out the pointless task of advancing much farther.

Therefore, one should use the setting **`AccuracyGoal -> Infinity`**.

The other issue one might infer from the discussion above is that a fixed step size will severely limit *Mathematica's* ability to home in on the singularity.  So the next recommendation is that **the `"FixedStep"` method should be discarded**.

Another issue is finding a spatial grid that yields an acceptable error estimate.  The OP used `"MinPoints" -> 180`.  I found `"MinPoints" -> 101` was sufficient to avoid a warning, but **`"MinPoints" -> 201`** produced a better looking graph.  (At some point I raised the `WorkingPrecision` to `40`.  I do not think this is strictly necessary.  It takes a long time to run a trial and such a difference in precision is relatively unimportant, so I did not experiment with it much.)

Here is the code I used.  It took almost half an hour.

```
sol = NDSolve[
  {D[h[x, t], t] + D[h[x, t]^-1*D[h[x, t], x], x] + D[h[x, t]^3*D[h[x, t], {x, 3}], x] == 0, 
   h[-((3 Sqrt[2] π)/2), t] == h[(Sqrt[2] π)/2, t], 
   h[x, 0] == 1 + 1/10*Sin[x/Sqrt[2]]},
  h,
  {x, -((3 Sqrt[2] π)/2), (Sqrt[2] π)/2},
  {t, 0, 6}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 201, "MaxPoints" -> 1001, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}},
  AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 40];
```

> `` NDSolve`Iterate::ndsz ``: At `` t == 4.08475454101253896091960366504686029429278350495484420555092981315002745816884`40. ``, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

We can check the domain and get the value of `t` reported in the warning message:

```
(h["Domain"] /. First[sol])[[2, 2]]
(* 4.08475454101253896091960366504686029429278350495484420555092981315002745816884`40. *)
```

We can see that the computed value of `h[-(Sqrt[2]*π)/2, t0]` is very small.  The derivative is quite large, so Newton's method estimates that the zero is within a little under `10^-36` of the last value calculated by `NDSolve`.

```
critpt = {x -> (-(Sqrt[2]*π)/2), t -> (h["Domain"] /. First[sol])[[2, 2]]};
h[x, t] /. First[sol] /. critpt // N
D[h[x, t], t] /. First[sol] /. critpt // N
%% / %
(*
  7.16714*10^-18    -- value of h
  -1.97906*10^19    -- t-derivative
  -3.62148*10^-37   -- error estimate for t (Newton's method)
*)
```

We can see that the spatial grid has 201 points and the time integration took almost 250 steps.  The last nine steps were very small indeed, around `10^-36` to `10^-37`.

```
(h["Grid"] /. First[sol]) // Dimensions
(h["Grid"] /. First[sol])[[1, -10 ;;, 2]] // Differences
(*
  {201, 246, 2}

  {1.419*10^-36, 2.218*10^-36, 1.609*10^-36, 1.504*10^-36, 1.96*10^-37, 
   1.96*10^-37, 3.07*10^-37, 2.22*10^-37, 2.08*10^-37}
*)
```

Let's check that the value of `h` has not crossed zero.  The midpoint of the spatial grid is position `101` and corresponds to `x == -(Sqrt[2] π)/2`.  The following returns the positions of any negative values along this line; there are none:

```
Position[(h["ValuesOnGrid"] /. First[sol2])[[101]], _?Negative]
(* {} *)
```

Here is a look at the solution.  One can see oscillations beginning to form at the time front, which suggests the error oscillations might be getting large.

```
Plot3D[h[x, t] /. First[sol],
 {x, -((3 Sqrt[2] π)/2), (Sqrt[2] π)/2},
 Evaluate@Prepend[(h["Domain"] /. First[sol])[[2]], t],
 PlotRange -> {0, All}, WorkingPrecision -> 40
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Caveat**

The value of `t` where `h` is zero depends on the accuracy of the computed solution.  I carried out the solution with `"MinPoints" -> 101`.  *Mathematica* did not complain about the solution, but the stopping point was about `4.08323`, which differs from the above stopping point by about `0.0015`.  That is a rather large difference.  The value of `h` was `6.34605*10^-18`, which is about the same.  One would also infer a similar estimate for the error in `t` (`4*10^-37`) from Newton's Method.  Probably there is an accumulation of error throughout the time integration.  One might consider doubling the spatial grid until a semblance of convergence occurs; perhaps `WorkingPrecision` might need to be increased.  I would expect that to take some computation time.  It seems feasible, but it is more time than I have to devote to this problem.

**Verification of oscillations when h ≈ 0**

The following was produce with a spatial grid of `101` points and an `AccuracyGoal` of `10`.  The first few hundred points (beyond the plot range) track the solution.  For the last 9000+ points, the steps oscillate between `±2*10^-8`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Michael.Thank you for your devoting to my problem. I'm so sorry for my late reply due to my cursoriness. Your answer is very helpful! Especially, you concluded **The value of t where h is zero depends on the accuracy of computation**. With time-derivative analysis combined time-integration along axis of symmetry, the suggestion `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity` is wonderful! Actually, I'm a MMA beginner. I do have some questions which could be easy to you:). 1. As you mentioned "`FixedStep` should be discarded", I used `StepSizeControlParameters` in my code, should it be varied time step method?

Comment: Let me continue :P. 2. You employed `"DifferenceOrder"-> "Pseudospectral"` to evaluate the spatial derivative, do you think there are any other method would work better, such as, `"DifferenceOrder" -> 2 or so`. 3. Is the ** Newton's method** you mentioned the method of time integration, and how can I get the error estimate for time step from Newton's Method, as in your post **-3.62148*10^-37   -- error estimate for t (Newton's method)**. 4. Please guide me to understand `[[1, -10 ;;, 2]] // Differences`, which you used to get the number of time steps and the last 9 step sizes. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ixy, hi and thanks! :)  I haven't used `"StepSizeControlParameters"`. The description in the manual makes it seem like it might help. `"DifferenceOrder"-> "Pseudospectral"` seemed to produce smaller spatial error estimates.  Each choice has advantages and disadvantages, which are discussed in the "The Numerical Method of Lines" tutorial. The Newton's Method estimate is a local estimate given by Newton's (tangent line) formula `Δt = -f[t]/f'[t]`. When the function is positive and concave down, this is a theoretical upper bound (but it ignores the accumulated global error of the integration)...

Comment: @Ixy:...In other words, from the computed solution, it is an upper limit on how far we can advance `t`. It shows that we have determined where the **computed approximation** is zero highly accurately; however, changing the spatial grid shows that the global error is significant. The notation `[[1, -10 ;;, 2]]` selects some of the values from the `{x, t}` grid used by `NDSolve`. The `1` gets the first line of integration; the `-10 ;;` code represents the last ten steps (look up `Span`); the `2` get the `t` part -- all in all, it is the last ten time steps. `Differences` gives the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I found another combination of option that doesn't suffer the `NDSolve::eerr` warning and produces almost the same result as that in [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) but only takes about 0.6 s on my old laptop to finish. The key point here is to use a **high enough** `"DifferenceOrder"` and choose a **odd** number of grid points:

```
(* Define a auxiliary function *)
mol[n_, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

AbsoluteTiming[
   sol = h /. First[NDSolve[{D[h[x, t], t] + D[D[h[x, t], x]/h[x, t], 
                   x] + D[h[x, t]^3 D[h[x, t], {x, 3}], x] == 0, 
             h[(-(1/2)) (3 Sqrt[2] Pi), t] == h[(Sqrt[2] Pi)/2, t], 
             h[x, 0] == 1 + (1/10) Sin[x/Sqrt[2]]}, h, 
           {x, (-(1/2)) (3 Sqrt[2] Pi), (Sqrt[2] Pi)/2}, {t, 0, 6}, 
           Method -> mol[75, 11]]]]

{{xl, xr}, {tl, tr}} = sol["Domain"];

Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, xl, xr}, {t, tl, tr}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]